# ASP.NET BundleConfig.cs does not appear to like minified version of Jquery for registering BootStrap later

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dependency-management

So I am playing around with ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2017 and was curious on the Bundle Config relationship.  I was reading that it was better for gathering multiple files for efficiency.  Yet it appears to not like a callout to the minified file for later references.  EG:

This:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

...

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

is fine and works fine.

This:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
              "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));

...

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

does not.  It appears that any form of

"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.**min**.js"))"

or

"~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.**min**.js"))"

will screw it up.  If I want third party javascript libraries and to bundle them for efficiency I would think I could bundle them minified.  Is it an issue with the registration of the Jquery min library to be recognized properly by Bootstrap?

Comment: try to add both file min and normal, and use into the bundle the version without min with the {versione} placeholder

Comment: @Darion I can get it working with the full version, I was curious on using minification for speed of loading only.  It works fine without minification which is the real issue.  I want to load minified files for faster loading.

Comment: into the web.config -> system.web -> compilation set the attribute debug=false

Comment: @Darion  That is missing in the web config, are you saying to add it?

Comment: yes, the tag should look like this: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">

Comment: @Darion Interesting so I could realistically debut my app then change the config(or have multiple configs for Dev, QA, Prod, etc) and then just have the minified for a different config setting.  That seems to work if I start up the project at least in Chrome and hit F12 and see what loaded.  It looks like it's all there.  Interesting it would be a compilation setting that has to do with minified libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the minified version changing the web.confing compilation tag setting the debug attribute to false like this:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
```

This is automatically set by Visual Studio to false when you publish the production version. Of course, if you need to test it in the develop enviroment, you can change it.